# Trying to set up a bridge, no luck!

Tags: relays, configuration, bridge, help

I'm relatively new to Tor, having read about it in my newspaper so I thought I'd give it a go.  Having read about relays and bridges and so forth I thought I'd try it out.

I managed to get a relay running by editing the Torrc file like so,

```
BandwidthRate 204800
ContactInfo ______.s@dsl.pipex.com
DataDirectory C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Data\Tor
ExitPolicy reject *:*
GeoIPFile C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\geoip6
Nickname HAVANASUN
ORPort 443
```

Then I tried to set it up as a bridge.  I entered these lines instead which I found on-line.

```
SocksPort 0
ORPort 443
BridgeRelay 1
Exitpolicy reject *:*
```

Won't connect!  I'm sure it's something simple but to be honest I'm not all that sharp with computers.

Can some kind soul help me out please?

PS, I'm using the Tor Browser, not Vidalia.

Thanks chaps

Comment: What errors are you experiencing?

Comment: Thank you, if I use the configuration I showed you Tor simply won't connect. I avoided using the Vidalia bundle as the Tor site recommended using the browser and editing the torrc file. What I'm after chaps is a simple walk-through of how to allow a bridge to run whilst still using the browser. Thanks

Comment: Do you have DirPort enabled? If yes, what port did you set it?
Are there any other services running on port 443?
I think you can't just simply set the ORPort to 443.
You have to use Port forwarding instead. try using another port.

Comment: Is your bridge achievable from the net? Did you setted up port forwarding?

Comment: Slightly off topic: Note that `ContactInfo` is public; if you're redacting it here, you should be aware that it will be viewable to anyone looking through the list of relays. Just wanted to make sure you're aware.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that Tor isn't working is very simple. When you added the bridge configuration lines, there were duplicate lines that already existed in your relay configuration lines. Mainly, it is `ORPort 443` duplication is what is causing the issue, because Tor will try to listen to this port a second time and will find it occupied, exiting thus with an error!

Your full `torrc` file should look like this:

`BandwidthRate 204800
ContactInfo ______.s@dsl.pipex.com
DataDirectory C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Data\Tor
ExitPolicy reject *:*
GeoIPFile C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\geoip6
Nickname HAVANASUN
ORPort 443
SocksPort 0
BridgeRelay 1`

and that will hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: and no need to remove SocksPort - it's a common role coexistance